# How to load angular 2 files within express sub-app

Tags: node.js, express, angular, heroku, deployment

I have an node application using express. I used express-generator to generate a default express setup.

I created two sub-applications that I will call "ang" and "admin" (also using the express-generator). These sub-applications are contained within another express application I will call "host".

"Ang"- Handles an angular2 application as well as its respective api (api made with express)

"Admin"- This allows the site owners to add new content to database that the api interfaces with.

This works well on my local dev environment, but when I push this to Heroku certain modules are not being installed (ie, the "admin" app is missing modules specific to it) and the build fails.

After copying relevant dependencies from the sub-apps package.jsons (from both express sub apps as well as the ang2 package.json) I was able to run the admin portion of the website, but was unable to run "ang" as it would encounter 404 errors as it searched for node_modules.

"host app.js"

```
/*required modules*/
var app = express();

/*Boths paths reference different sub apps*/
var ang = require('./path/to/app.js');
var admin = require('./path/to/app.js');

/*Routes each app uses*/
app.use('/base', admin);
app.use('/', ang);

module.exports = app;
```

How do I route to the node-modules contained within the "host" app?

Answer (score 0):

So after removing node_modules from my localhost and attempting to build it I understood why I was unable to find the packages by changing the paths in the index.html of my ang2 app.

My angular2 app is contained within a static directory. So, I needed to utilize the power of the node package manager (npm). So I altered the package.json of my "host" app. I altered the "scripts" field from:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

to

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www",
  "postinstall": " cd /path/from/host/to/ang/client_directory && npm install"
},
```

After installing the host app package.json "postinstall" command is run. See [npm's scripts documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for more information. This will [cd](http://www.linfo.org/cd.html) into the directory and then run npm install from there which will find angular2 package.json.

**ALSO:** I am not sure if moving all the dependencies from the other package.json files is necessary if you simply setup the post-install field correctly.

Hope this saves you some trouble!